# How to create a stub for an indexed property with MS Fakes

Tags: unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

I have a interface that I need to mock which has indexer properties that partially looks like this.

```
 public interface MyInterface{         
     string this[string name] {get;set;};
     string this[int index] {get;set;};
 }
```

I would like to mock out the interface such that certain values for name and index above return the values I supply. How can I achieve this with the Microsoft Fakes Framework?

Answer (score 6):

You can simply utilize Microsoft Fakes to stub this functionality in a test. Right click on your target assembly (the project that includes the interface definition) and select add Fakes assembly in the references of your test project.

The Fake assembly generated will be, "TargetAssembly.Fakes". In that assembly you will have a type "StubMyInterface" with methods, "ItemGetInt32", "ItemGetString", "ItemSetInt32String", "ItemSetStringString", which is stub implementations of the 3 get / set methods.

You can use them in a test as follows.

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyInterfaceTest()
{
    var stub = new StubMyInterface()
    {
        ItemGetInt32 = (x) => { return "teststring"; }
    };

    MyInterface SUT = stub;
    var result = SUT[47];

    Assert.AreEqual("teststring", result);
}
```

Comment: This should be marked as the answer as this is correct. Thanks for the detailed answer Joshua!